# Branching to different subroutines in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

Say I have the following assembly code:

```
subroutineA:
   ....some assembly code....

subroutineB:
   ....some assembly code....

subroutineC:
   ....some assembly code....
```

Now, in another subroutine, I want to build something that will randomly branch to one of the 3 subroutines above.

Something like:

```
subroutineD:
  ....some code to randomly branch to either 
       subroutineA, or subroutineB, or subroutineC ....
```

How can do this efficiently in ARM assembler?

Here is how I ended up solving the issue and it might help someone else some day (pseudo code below):

I declared an array in Assembly to store all the subroutine label (their memory address):

```
.global my_arr
my_arr:
    .long subroutineA
    .long subroutineB  
    .long subroutineC
    .......
```

I also have some random number generator in Assembly (LFSR). Say I have have the random number in `R0` (of course, make sure random number between 0 and total number of subroutine), then I would do something like:

```
ldr R4, =my_arr
ldr R5, [R4, R0]
```

And then in `R5`, I have address of random subroutine. And then I can simply do:

```
blr R5
```

to go to the subroutine.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I guess what you are suggesting, is first generate a number, and then do a compare, if number is 1, do bl subroutineA, if number is 2, do bl subroutineB, and so on. But what if I have many many subroutines, this becomes terribly inefficient no ? Maybe I'm not understanding what you are saying ?

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm new to assembly, and I'm just trying to learn what would be best way to go about such a thing. Say in C (or some other language), I would store all my subroutines in some structure, and generate a random number, and jump to the subroutines at that index in the structure.

Comment: You can do pretty much exactly the same thing in assembly language. Create an array of function addresses, and based on the random number, do an indirect call to one of the functions in that array.

Comment: Jump tables are probably simpler in assembly than in most higher-level languages. If this question is really about a particular implementation of "some code" to "build something", it should probably _say so_.

Comment: @Notlikethat and GregHewgill Thanks for the suggestions, I will give those a try. These are the exact suggestions I'm looking for. I'm new to assembly, and I wasn't sure what was the best approach to the problem. I'm not looking for precise code to build it. Just wanted suggestions. How can I change the question to not get a bunch of down votes next time ?

Comment: @JJackJi The #1 rule is _be more specific_ - you clearly understand your goal, but you've presented us with a vague mix of ideas: "How to implement an RNG algorithm in assembly" is one question, "How to call `rand()` from assembly code" is a different one, "How best to dispatch different function calls based on a variable" is a third. The first two, once clearly defined, are easily searchable (in fact, a simple linear congruential generator is trivially easy in C, so would make a good assembly exercise). The third would warrant more details, e.g. do all the functions have the same signature?

Comment: @Notlikethat Just updated, is it better now ?

Answer (score 1):

You may efficiently implement a jump table like this,

```
 adr lr, return
 cmp r0, #3
 ldrlo pc, [pc, r0, lsl #2] @ pc is 8 bytes ahead
 b  error                   @ also functions as padding
.long subroutineA
.long subroutineB  
.long subroutineC
return:
 @ one of three routines finished here.
...
error:
 @ random out of array range.
```

This is very generic.  David Seal gives a nice way to implement a switch type statement in *9.2.5 Multi-Way branch* of the ARM ARM 2nd edition,

```
 cmp   r0,#max
 addlo pc, pc, r0, LSL #routineSizeLog2
 b     outOfRange
index0:
 ...
index1:
 ...
index2:
 ...
```

Compilers usually do my first version (function pointer type), but do not need to save `lr` to implement a switch.  Usually `case` statements are not so linear.  However, many people create interrupt handlers, etc in assembler using David Seal's method.

Comment: Well, that is not the only way compilers implement switches, but it is one common way.