# Arm 7 If/Else Statement

Tags: arm, arm7

**How do I convert this example of psuedo code to Arm 7??**

```
if R8 == 1, Go to "method 1"
else, Go to "method 2"
```

Also in "method 1" R8 is changed to two (R8=2), so the next time around I want it to access "method 2". So I wanted the loop to alternate between method 1 and 2

Comment: You must show some effort than asking questions without giving a shot yourself. Are you also sure you want this for Arm 7? If this is for newer generations you want ARMv7. Arm 7 is a really old core.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Branching to different subroutines in ARM assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110034/branching-to-different-subroutines-in-arm-assembly)

Answer (score 1):

```
cmp r8, #1
bleq method1
cmp r8, #1 //method1 may alter CPSR
blne method2
```

see http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHIDDID.html

Comment: I would investigate `adrCC rX,methodYY` and a final `bl rx` to avoid the re-compare.  I think the table method in the other question/answer is just as good, even for two values and will work if the method1 trashes `r8` (assembler may not follow the APCS).

Comment: How would i form a branch if the value R8 is odd?

Comment: Indeed, with more methods, I would put them in an array, and compute an offset to call the right one, but here, I only have two choices, and ldr may cost much time.
@TaylorAustin, look in the [ARM documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHIDDID.html) you've got an instruction for bitwise tests.