# Is there translate-table XLAT instruction in ARM programming?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm new to ARM programming and I was wondering if there is a translate-table instruction xlat in ARM cause I used it in Intel 8086  ?

Comment: This [question on multiple sub-routines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110034/branching-to-different-subroutines-in-arm-assembly) may also be interesting.  Instead of `XLAT` for data, it is the same concept for code on the ARM.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of `XLAT` is that it is a table lookup.

This is standard to all ARM CPUs.  It is called [double register indirect](http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/301/ARM-addressing/lecture.html) and looks like,

```
 ldrb r0, [r1, r2]  ; get memory location r1+r2 and place in r0.
```

The form with scaling is useful for accessing 'half-word', 'word', 'double-word' and other power of 2 data structures.

There is also a *thumb2* instructions [`TBB` and `TBH`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204f/Cjafifbd.html), but this is a slightly different form that is used for `switch` statement or jump table.  The ARM mode instruction maybe used as,

```
ldr  pc, [r1, r2, lsl #2]  ; set pc to r1 + 4*r2.
```

Comment: Great answer. I removed mine as it distracts from yours which shows how to elegantly acccomplish this in ARM. I forgot how flexible the addressing actually was.