# Addressing a label with a shifted offset in ARM asm

Tags: assembly, arm, syntax-error

I'm interested in using a counter in a loop to continually load in an array of strings using Arm assembly.
The strings are spaced by 16 bytes and have an index offset in r4.

```
@r4 contains 0
printInventory:
    ldr     r0, =PrintLetter
    ldr     r1, [=FirstString,r4, LSL #4] @Loads the address of (FirstString + 16*r4)
    bl      printf
//snip
    add     r4, r4, #1
    b printInventory
```

This syntax is not accepted by the compiler. What is an acceptable way to implement something like this?

Comment: Increment a pointer in R4.  ARM addressing modes only have like 8 or 12 bits of displacement, not enough for a a full absolute address.  And that pseudo-instruction syntax only exists for bare values.  Look at compiler-generated asm for an example (https://godbolt.org/ has ARM GCC and Clang; write equivalent C like with global variables.)

Comment: You may like [this question on ARM labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774581/getting-an-label-address-to-a-register-on-arm).   Some depends on the CPU type.  For instance, [`XLAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085772/is-there-translate-table-xlat-instruction-in-arm-programming) can be of use with variable sized strings.  You can also have an array of pointer and then reload the address.  This allows for variable sized strings.  `UXTAB`, `TBB`, `TBH` and `printf()`  return value may also be of interest.  It is always important to get data structures right.

Comment: Err, TBB, and TBH are better for execution (switch statements on reflection).  Probably the double index may work best for you (to allow arbitrary string lengths).  Or simple iteration with the `printf()` return value.  Ie, but put `=FirstString` in a register.  ARM does not support direct memory loads and the `ldr r1, =FirstString` is a bit of a misleading pseudo-op which the 'question on ARM labels' answer tries to explain.  `ADR` is probably the better pseudo-op for assembler programmers.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that when loading a label, it actually is loading an offset to the pc, ie:

```
ldr r1, =FirstString
```

is actually

```
ldr r1, [pc, #0x20]
```

or whatever the offset to the label happens to be.
I realize that means that what I'm doing just won't work. My way around this is the following:

```
printInventory:
ldr     r0, =PrintLetter
ldr     r1, =FirstString @Loads the address of FirstString
add     r1, r1, r4, LSL #4
bl      printf
//snip
add     r4, r4, #1
b printInventory
```

I hope this helps if you were having similar issues, and thank you to those who commented.

Comment: *or whatever the offset to the label happens to be* - Actually the PC-relative load is from a nearby "literal pool", so the offset is actually to an address the assembler invented, where it stuck a word of data between functions somewhere within range of this `ldr`.  That word is the absolute address of the actual label, `FirstString`.  If the address was in range to reach directly, `add r1, pc, #0x20` or something would be possible for that `ldr` (there's an `adr` instruction which is something like that.)  But yes, that's one way to do this.